# Change Kernel from 4.2 to 3.13 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel, virtualbox

I want to run Pin(Intel's Simulator) but it is not supported in Kernel 4.2 version, so I should change it to 3.13 that works for sure.

[image]

I run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (32bit) in VirtualBox and i followed the instructions i found

[e[image]

But when I tried to run pin I saw "E:4.2 is not a supported linux release".

Could you help me please?

Comment: Why would you provide information as image which can be posted as text (readable, searchable, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy to downgrade kernel in 14.04.

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Then remove all 4.2 kernel image and headers packages using Synaptic.

As an option you can leave 4.2 kernels and just boot with 3.13 using grub.

According to your screenshots you already have some 3.13 kernel installed.

Comment: Thanks for youn answer,but as i am a beginner in linux(i did not mentioned) i do not know how to boot from another kernel.Could  you please tell me how to boot using 3.13 that i have already installed? :)

Comment: You need to enter grub menu by holding Shift or ESC on boot. The select Advanced options. And you will see all kernels installed and you will be able to select one.

Comment: It worked!!!(pressing esc) Thanks a lot for your help!! :)

Comment: And you do not need to install mainline kernels from debs. You can have standard 3.13 Ubuntu kernels with updates.

Comment: @Pilot6 wow, why I haven't found ESC key for grub before. Everywhere I've seen left shift. huh

Answer (score -1):

Install with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.0.0-12-generic linux-headers-3.0.0-12-generic
```

and remove all 4.2 kernel image and headers packages using Synaptic.

Comment: There are no these packages in trusty repos.

Comment: install from GitHub or Launchpad repositories or download in kernel.org

Comment: There is absolutely no need to do that.